# Why did the "community" user reject my edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user

I was reviewing my suggested edits, and saw that the "community" user rejected three of my edits because they "conflicted with a subsequent edit."

**What's that supposed to mean?** I've had very few rejected edits.

I'm referring to:

- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/570310
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/570008
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/570308

Comment: Funny thing is, I just made an edit at the same time as you here http://askubuntu.com/questions/779496/execute-comands-to-speed-up-wireless-and-pci-stop-runing and this same thing happened. I did not reject it, I just have elevated privileges, sorry :)

Comment: @MarkKirby - Not your fault :) I need a few more good answers, and then I'll be able to make instant edits.

Comment: I don't think it has any effect on your account, just bad luck. I would of gone with yours as they were much the same and I feel for you, those first 2 -3 K are the hardest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each of those pages tell you:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

In practice that means: somebody started editing before you submitted your edit and they didn't require approval for their edit to go through. There are two reasons somebody might not need approval for their edit. It was their post or they have more than 2,000 reputation. A mixture of the two applied to your examples.

This is an unfortunate race condition in the system but it picks the option with the easiest future. Here, that's the one that doesn't require other people to come in and say it's a good edit or not. Your edit gets rejected automatically as theirs is implemented.

Comment: I'm working hard to get to 2k rep so my edits don't need approval. I'm 3/4 the way there :)

Comment: @AndroidDev It's very nice that you take the time to improve posts but please do not do that for the sake of getting points and wanting to get edits without approval. E.g. in the first edit there was absolutely no need to turn the computers spec in some kind of code block. That is not code at all.