# Made an edit to a question but didn't get credit for it. Instead, OP did

Tags: discussion, support

I just edited this question: [Incorrect resolution and no wifi and no usb after update](https://askubuntu.com/q/836595/301745), but didn't get credit for it. Instead, the credit seems to have gone to OP. What happened there? Did OP copy-paste my edit and claim it as his own, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5):

Your edit was rejected because the OP was already editing when you submitted your edit. You can tell by [the Community bot rejecting your edit.](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/629538) For more information see: [Why did the community user reject my edits?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15439/why-did-the-community-user-reject-my-edits)

Comment: That would seem to confirm that OP copy-pasted my edit, no? Look at his edit at the same time. It's exactly the same.

Comment: @wjandrea It does appear that way, but that cannot have happened because editing the post is locked while a review is pending and he did not reject your edit himself (although he could have), but the community user rejected it because he submitted an edit he had already been working on after yours was submitted. I'll see if I can get a developer's take on this though, because the edits are identical, other than a little bit in the title. I don't see how he could have managed that..

Comment: Only 31 seconds elapsed from your suggested edit to his edit being submitted. I guess that is theoretically enough time for him to have started editing the title, you submit your edit, he sees the notification and then copies your edit in as well as his title edit.. but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the edit, I see all the individual changes made so I don't see how the OP could have simply copied and pasted your edit. If that is indeed your work, it would seem to be a bug....