# Edit conflicted with a subsequent edit

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

Sometimes I like editing questions by adding relevant tags, helping with formatting and overall question refining.

I don't usually get the edit rejected, but this time is was by [Community♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community), stating `"This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"`.

The thing is: I refined the whole question and added relevant tags, and it seems that the asking user also edited the question after my edit suggestion, replacing 4 words of my original edit.
Thus resulting the question to be using my exact edit suggestion (except those 4 words), and represented as their own edit.

Why would the system count my edit as a reject?
And if so, why did the question keep all my changes?

Here is a screenshot of that action:

[image: sc]

**Edit**: In contrast to the thread suggested in the comments ([Why did the “community” user reject my edits?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15439/why-did-the-community-user-reject-my-edits)), it seems I submitted the edit first, and the user who asked and edited his question had no elevated privileges. 
And while that thread suggests a possible reason for that to happen, I don't seem to really understand why and how all the changes I submitted were saved and used, but edit is considered as rejected.

Although I'm perfectly okay with the question overall got improved (no matter how it was done), at the bottom line it currently consists of all my changes while it was counted as a rejected edit, and market as if the user who asked the question done all the changes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but unfortunately no. I edited the question, trying to explain it better.

Comment: "and the user who asked and edited his question had no elevated privileges" All users have elevated privileges on their own posts, the OP can overwrite you edit. As to how they incorporated your changes, only the OP know that for a fact but they likely copied it from the edit review page, into the question edit page and then submitted it. Some people are really funny about edits, don't worrie about it, soon you will reach 2k.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. It was less about the rep points, and more about understanding the mechanism of how this might have happened. It does make you feel a bit cheated about the reject count though.

Comment: I can understand how it feels when suggested edit on which you spent 5-10 mins gets rejected with no reason. I, myself, was in similar situation once. As of now you have only 4 edits rejected while I have 6. These numbers don't really matter unless the number of rejected ones overtake that of approved ones. So keep suggesting constructive edits :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one way this can happen quite by accident. If you go `/posts/<id>/edit` (e.g., https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/19090/edit for this question), *while an editing is pending*, (a) the editing window will show the version from the pending edit and (b) if you save the edit there, the pending edit gets rejected, even though its contents were applied.

You can reach that link by, e.g., clicking on an `[edit]` magic link left in the comments, or if you'd left the post open but it hadn't got refreshed for some reason (so the `edit` link under the question wouldn't have been replaced by the edit pending one).

I think this was likely an accident.

[Edits that shadow a suggested edit inconsistently reject but include the suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262314/270345)